# Raspi / Problem running script to toggle GPIO over web with a webpage

Tags: html, raspberry-pi, iot

I'm trying to control an LED light by toggling GPIO pin on a RaspberryPi over the web.

index.html (below) has two buttons to run functions which will trigger the two scripts (lighton.cgi and lightoff.cgi) to control GPIO directly. I verified the scripts which will turn on or off the LED. But somehow when I click the button on index.html, it will not turn on or off LED.

Is there a syntax error in my index.html? or has there been a change in html convention? Can someone please help me?

**index.html code:**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="lighton()">Turn On</button>
<br><br>
<button onclick="lightoff()">Turn Off</button>
<script>
var xmlhttp;
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
function lighton()
    {
        xmlhttp.open("GET","cgi-bin/lighton.cgi",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
function lightoff()
    {
        xmlhttp.open("GET","cgi-bin/lightoff.cgi",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**lighton.cgi code:**

```
#!/bin/bash
gpio -g write 10 1
```

[b]lightoff.cgi code:[/b]

```
#!/bin/bash
gpio -g write 10 0
```

I basically followed MJRoBot's tutorial below:
https://www.hackster.io/mjrobot/iot-controlling-a-raspberry-pi-robot-over-internet-6988d4#toc-step-1--bill-of-material-1

Answer (score 0):

There is at least an opening `<scipt>` missing in your html:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="lighton()">Turn On</button>
<br><br>
<button onclick="lightoff()">Turn Off</button>
<script>
var xmlhttp;
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
function lighton()
    {
        xmlhttp.open("GET","cgi-bin/lighton.cgi",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
function lightoff()
    {
        xmlhttp.open("GET","cgi-bin/lightoff.cgi",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this wont work, check the console (F12) to see if your javascript throws any errors, or the ajax is sent to your raspi.

Comment: Sorry, I did not copy completely. <script> opening was in there but it still did not work.

Comment: You should try the browsers debugger to see what the problem is. Try to use a full address in your xmlhttp.open() commands, including your raspies ip or hostname - e.g. `xmlhttp.open("GET","https://raspie:8000/cgi-bin/lightoff.cgi",true);` or whatever your ip/port is, othewise it will only work if you run the webbrowser on the raspi itself, but not any other computer in your network.